# How to skin mx:Image source through CSS?

Tags: apache-flex

For example, it is possible to embed an image...

```
[Embed("myImage.png")]
public var myImage:Class;
```

and assign it to the mx:Image's source property like this :

```
<mx:Image source="{myImage}" />
```

but what if I want to be able to load the image from a compiled CSS file, something like:

```
.myImage {some-property: Embed("myImage.png"); }
```

What is the cleanest way to assign this kind of styled image to the mx:Image's source property ?

Comment: I want to style mx:Image through CSS, title is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution:

You can load images in a component, spark Panel in this case :

```
s|Panel {
    myImage: Embed(source="assets/images.swf", symbol="simple_image");
    myOtherImage: Embed(source="assets/images.swf", symbol="other_image");
}
```

and then, when you change styles at runtime, you can react on StyleEvent.COMPLETE event:

```
var css:CSSStyleDeclaration = StyleManager.getStyleManager(null).getStyleDeclaration("spark.components.Panel");
var myImage:Object = css.getStyle("myImage");
var myOtherImage:Object = css.getStyle("myOtherImage");
```

From there you can easily assign those custom styled images to your mx:Image component's source.